# How to detect status connection in a network with password?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have a feature in my app related with the status connection (depending of the status network I have a red or green circle) and It is working correctly detecting if has network available, but I have a question when the network needs a password to access correctly,for example: app detects a free network and appears like "you are online" (in this case green indicator) but you do not have possibility to connect or connectivity because you are not writing the pass for instance..

How to detect correctly when the user has real connectivity?

Here a post with a different approach:

https://www.kirupa.com/html5/check_if_internet_connection_exists_in_javascript.htm

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using Javascript you can only use the `navigator` object, to check *online* status.
Something like this:

```
var isOnline = navigator.connection.type !== Connection.NONE;
```

So you'll only be able to detect if any connection is *active* when you test connectivity status; if a connection needs authentication, and it has not been authenticated yet, it will not be *active*, so you will **not** be able to detect it from Javascript...

Of course using Cordova you'll be able to do something more useful, like listening for online/offline events:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState) {
  doSomethingWhenNetworkGoesOnline();
});

// listen for Offline event
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState) {
  doSomethingWhenNetworkGoesOffline();
});
```

But the point is the same: no connection, no party... :-)

Comment: Currently my implementation is very similar to this...I will try another solution, thank you for your response...

Comment: If you find a better solution, please post it here, I'm quite curious... :-)

Comment: Here I have other approach about this: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/check_if_internet_connection_exists_in_javascript.htm

Comment: That approach is however not perfect: what if the **other end** server was offline and you perfectly connected? :-)

Comment: but maybe, you can test if the "ping" is responding or not, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112307/discussion-between-inane-and-marcos).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution for you involves a server, instead of trusting on isOnline methods, launch a WS against a public or private method, so if you get a response, you have real connectivity.

Comment: any example about this solution?

Comment: This solution is fine, but is not well suited if you want to attach some action on network connectivity change... And, it's a bit slow to respond in case on absence of connectivity, due to timeouts...

Comment: Did you check the Cordova code in my answer? It has no 'quirks', and it works great...

Comment: Well, your cordova answer only depends that the network have assigned you an IP, and have some kind of connection (maybe an internal login in semi-private Wifis). Doing this you ensure that you have real connection to the internet.

Comment: Here I have other approach about this: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/check_if_internet_connection_exists_in_javascript.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can't trust navigator connection type nor cordova network detection feature for what you want, their behavior are quite random. You may think about testing a http server with a http call. And when promise got resolve you can put your light to green.

in angular :

```
$http.get('http://google.com').then(function(){ $scope.color = 'green'; });
```

And you would run this in a interval block every 5 or 10 sec to update your view.
Of course you would replace google.com by a server of yours.

Comment: Why do you say it is 'random'? It works perfectly, for me... :-)

Comment: because you may have to manage all the platform quirks by yourself and in the end it doesnt mean you really have connectivity to internet and to your server.